# Remove adwares ( taboola, outbrain etc ) from Chrome/Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, malware

How to remove "around the web" by outbrain or recommended by taboola from google chrome or firefox on ubuntu ?

I tried removing content of

> `rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome`

install and re-install google-chrome but all in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (disgusting) "around the web" is added by websites themselves to make money off ads.

The only thing you can do is to install an ad-blocker.

I recommend the open source uBlock Origin ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/); code at [GitHub](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock)). Get uBlock **Origin**, not uBlock — that is a discontinued fork.

Comment: ah that would make sense :D

Comment: any info about taboola?

Comment: @azeem It says it's a "content discovery platform". Websites that put up Taboola ads are paid some money on each click of the Taboola ads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for this. Within the browsers 'Notification Settings' you can control **all** websites permissions to send notifications. Not only you'll get a list of possible candidates you can also block them actively.

### For Firefox

- Open top right (3 bar) application menu ->

  - Settings ->

    - Privacy and Security ->

      - Permissions ->

        - **Notifications -> Settings** -> block website

Either determine specifically the website which adds them by systematic enable/disable/restart or just disable all potential candidates for a quick fix.

Don't forget to **Restart firefox**. Notifications should be gone presumed you disable the right websites.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar. the adware will be in your profile, so a browser re-install is useless.

A/ in chromium, do: 1/ settings/ advanced/ reset settings.  this worked for me.  2/ next, install extension "chrome adware removal". this ext seems best to block and strip adware before it infects.

B/ if you have a malware, you can try clamav, but I have found a wipe and system reinstall to be the only sure means to disinfect.